# Where are BigQuery tab indentation settings?

Tags: google-bigquery

How do you choose how many spaces a `tab` inserts in gcp's SQL workspace editor?

In some scripts it does 2, in others it is 4, and I can't find a place to control that setting

edit due to comments:

Suppose I have query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `dwh.dataset.table`
order by uid, registration_date
```

Pressing `Tab` makes 4 spaces. `Format Query` will format it with 2 spaces:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `dwh.dataset.table`
ORDER BY
  uid,
  registration_date
```

If you add something after `Format Query` and are using `Tab` - it will still insert 4 spaces on new lines, while it will do 2 spaces on existing lines some times.. eg:

Writing code after format query:

```
SELECT
  uid,
  registration_date,
  sum(some_column) over (
      #<- why is there 4 spaces here now?
  )
FROM
  `dwh.dataset.table`
GROUP BY 
    #<- also here
ORDER BY
  uid,
  registration_date
```

Comment: Apparently the code alignment was designed by the BigQuery UI team and there may be no explicit setting to change the indentation spaces. Using the `Format Query` option will indent the query with 2 spaces. In the new BigQuery UI, pressing the `Tab` key indents 4 spaces. While in the old UI the `Tab` indent is 2 spaces.

Comment: Are you using the `Format Query` option and also using `Tab` indents? Also, share some examples where the indents are misaligned.

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj added more explanation & code

Comment: When `Tab` indentation is used after formatting the query (which introduces 2 spaces), it seems that the text is indented to the nearest 4 space indentation after which every `Tab` indents by 4 spaces. Most text editors exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: With that being said, I have raised this indentation discrepancy in Google’s Issue Tracker. The issue number is [#221400679](https://issuetracker.google.com/221400679). You can provide more details about the indentation in the Issue Tracker, if need be. You can also **`STAR`** the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).